# django urls from models

Tags: python, django, url, model

I have the following model:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES, max_length=10, default='online')
    categ = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesCategories)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.TextField()

    def get_edit_url(self):
       return '/articles/add/%d' % self.pk

    edit_url = property(get_edit_url)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'articles'
```

and the url route:

```
    url(r'^add/(?P<article_id>\d+)$', views.add_article, name='edit_articles'),
```

How do I have to edit the "get_edit_url" function so the url for edit article to be generated dynamically and to be able to change the path only from urls.py ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[This is a common problem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), django provides the tools to do it using the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) function

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_edit_url(self):
    # assuming your app isn't namespaced
    return reverse('edit_articles', args=(self.pk,))
    # if your app was namespaced it would be something like 
    # reverse('articles:edit_articles')
```

Comment: In Django 3, the import is `from django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `reverse` with model method:

from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_detail_url(self):
       return reverse('article-detail', args=(self.pk,))

    def get_list_url(self):
       return reverse('article-list')
```

This approach is more RESTful, `detail_view` will allow to get,delete,update an instance and `list_view` will allow to get list or eventually make bulk delete/update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-model-urls](https://github.com/vinyll/django-model-urls) to do that automatically without even altering your model!

#### Using your example:

urls.py

```
url(r'^add/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.add_article, name='edit_articles'),
```

some template:

```
{{ url('edit_articles', article) }}
```

(Note that current version use [jingo](https://github.com/jbalogh/jingo), raw Django template can use the [0.3.1 version](https://github.com/vinyll/django-model-urls/tree/0.3.1))